# matplotlib for Python 3.2 produces corrupt eps files on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a python script for making plots using matplotlib, and saving them as .eps files. If I run it on my Mac, it produces corrupted .eps files. If I try to open the .eps files with Preview, I get a pdf conversion error and they do not open. If I run pdflatex on a .tex file using the .eps files in figures, I get the error

```
<use ./foo-eps-converted-to.pdf>Error: /dictstackunderflow in --end--
```

though, oddly enough, the .pdf file does open and displays the plots correctly—and if I rerun pdflatex without removing any of the '-eps-converted-to.pdf' files, which also open just fine, then this error does not reappear. On the other hand, if I use latex, then dvips, then the resulting postscript document cannot be opened by Preview, and then ps2pdf fails with the error

```
Error: /undefined in ocount
```

and the resulting .pdf file contains only the first figure (and ends immediately thereafter).

Now, if I run the same python script on Linux, I don't encounter any problems with the .eps files. I opened the .eps files produced on both operating systems using nano, and noticed a discrepancy at the end of the file. The file ends with

```
%%PageTrailer
%%Trailer
end
cleartomark
countdictstack
exch sub { end } repeat
restore
%%EOF
```

on Linux, and

```
%%PageTrailer
%%Trailer
cleartomark
countdictstack
exch sub { end } repeat
restore
end
%%EOF
```

on Mac. If I manually move the line with the word 'end' in the file produced on Mac to where it is in the Linux file, the .eps file opens in Preview, and a LaTeX document using the file in a figure will compile correctly, without any errors, using either pdflatex or latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf.

For what it's worth, I am running Mac OS X 10.7.5, and using Python 3.2 and matplotlib installed through macports. (So python32, presently at version 3.2.5, and py32-matplotlib, presently at version 1.3.1.)

While I do have workarounds to the problem (I can use pdflatex and just ignore the errors, or I can manually edit the .eps files, or I can just do all of my plots on my Linux machine), I would like if I could deal with the problem at its root. However, I don't really understand what the cause of it is—why the .eps file produced by matplotlib on my Mac is different from the Linux one, or why this difference even produces an error—so I do not know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help that can be given, and apologies if this has been asked before (though I could not find any indication that it has been).

Comment: Please report this to the github issue tracker and include a minimal script which will generate such a file + files in question.  This looks like a major bug which should be fixed before we cut out 1.4.

Comment: It is still not solved